# How can I put a map output into a single collection

Tags: dictionary, clojure

Given the following:

```
user> (map (fn [x] (map #(* x %) '(1 2))) '(2 3))  
((2 4) (3 6))
```

In clojure how can I make change this idiomatically so that the output becomes:

```
(2 4 3 6)
```

I used lists to ilustrate, but any collection is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(mapcat (fn [x] (map #(* x %) '(1 2))) '(2 3))
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
(apply concat (map (fn [x] (map #(* x %) '(1 2))) '(2 3)))
```

`concat` concatenates collections together into one sequence. Calling it with `apply` allows you to pass a collection of collections to be concatenated.

Answer (score 3):

I might use `mapcat` here as Justin does, but in many similar cases `for` is a great tool for building collections. For example, I think this is a pretty legible way to write your function:

```
repl-1=> (for [x      '(2 3)
repl-1=*       factor '(1 2)]
repl-1=*   (* x factor))
(2 4 3 6)
```